# OSM or Google Tile problem fitting to Geopandas Dataframe

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geopandas, matplotlib

I found this good [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476117/easy-openstreetmap-tile-displaying-for-python) on how to get basemap tiles from open sources like OSM, Google, Bing, ESRI using python in geographic lat/long. I'm now trying to add the tiles I successfully got into a matplotlib plot in combination with geopandas dataframe data - which is Projected coordinates.

Getting Geopandas project areas:

```
aoiD = "o2_boundary.bdy_proj_projectarea" # dataset to query
aoiF = "name"                             # Field to use in query
aoiT = "My Project Site"                  # Value of field I want for query
con = psycopg2.connect(database=databaseCh, user=userP, password=passP,host=hostP)
sql = "SELECT {},geom FROM {}".format(aoiF,aoiD)
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql, con)
minx, miny, maxx, maxy = gdf.geometry.total_bounds
```

Skipping the part where I convert minx, maxx, miny, maxy to geographic coordinates....but I essentially had to pick the centre of the bounding box but creating an average X and Y in geographic coordinates.

Getting Tiles

```
a, bbox = getImageCluster(yG, xG, 0.02,  0.05, 14,r"https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={1}&y={2}&z={0}")
ax.imshow(np.asarray(a),zorder=1,extent=[minx, maxx, miny, maxy])
```

If I set the extent in imshow to the bounding box of the tiles data, then it does line up, with a bit of error mind. However, I don't want the tile extent - I need to force it to the project area extent. The image should show what happens when I set the extent to the project area min,max X/Y. The imagery is way off.

I couldn't figure out how to change the getImageCluster function to accept projected coordinates. I also can't find any documentation on what the 0.02 and 0.05 figures are for - apart from in the original post "delta_lat,delta_long". Do I need to calculate this delta, the difference of the minx,maxx? I have no idea. The function needs one X, one Y and one Z/Zoom. I would like to provide a bounding box instead. Or request a bigger area, then clip. But I don't know how to clip it and marry it up with the rest of my plot.

Since I couldn't change the request to a bounding box I got different extents of the 2 source datasets :

Geopandas layer /Provided Project Area Box:

X_min: 305293.73475847783. X_max: 316160.562743328. Y_min: 238490.12341525586. Y_max: 245986.05093984905

Bounding Box of Tiled Basemap:

X_min: 309767.457047739. X_max: 314045.453068257. Y_min: 241176.638187177. Y_max: 245650.729011243

And the result is pretty bad, imagery that doesn't line up to the vector data. Any thoughts or different approaches - can the tiled array be filtered with coordinates?

[image]

Comment: You would be able to keep much more hair if you simply used https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/plotting_basemap_background.html ;)

Comment: I wasn't able to get contextily working from multiple examples online. Error: partially initialized module 'contextily' has no
attribute 'bounds2img' (most likely due to a circular import), or no attribute 'add_basemap'/ 'Place' depending on the example.